# IIS7 and WCF confusion

Tags: wcf, iis-7

Assume I’m running a website ( on IIS7 ) listening for requests on port 8000. Now this website contains only static content ( ie html files ). So when I browse to URL http://localhost:8000, browser displays website’s default html page. But if I’m also running a self-hosting WCF service listening for requests on URL http://localhost: 8000 ( this WCF service isn’t hosted by IIS ), then browser instead displays data about WCF service:

a) Don’t know much about TCP/IP, but as far as I know only one application at a time can listen on particular IP and port, but here both the website and WCF service are able to listen on the same IP address and port number. How is that possible?

b) When I enter a local url ( say http://localhost:8000 ) into browser, doesn’t browser request a page via IIS? If so, then why does it display details of a WCF service and not a website’s default page? Afterall, this WCF service isn’t even hosted by IIS.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that normally, only a single process can listen on a specific socket. However, work was done in Windows to support this specifically for HTTP listeners, specifically with the introduction of [HTTP.SYS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a2a45c42-38bc-464c-a097-d7a202092a54.mspx?mfr=true) in IIS 6.0.

Basically, with this it is the kernel that actually listens for the HTTP requests and then the connection is routed to one of multiple listener processes in user-land.

The WCF HTTP listeners for self-hosting rely on HTTP.sys as well, so they can share ports with IIS if needed (or across multiple self-hosted WCF services).

Comment: A - But why does Http.Sys deliver request to WCF service and not IIS? B - So even "local" browsers ( thus residing on same machine as IIS ) don't directly "contact" IIS, but rather indirectly via Http.sys?

Comment: No one contacts IIS directly; nor do the applications (local or not) choose who to contact. The listening socket itself is monitored by the windows kernel on behalf of any processes that have registered themselves with HTTP.SYS. Then it will look at the path specified in the HTTP request and decide where to route (what listening process) the request to.

Comment: I should've added that part of your current issue is that you have both WCF and IIS using the same base address, which makes it hard to decide who should process the request. You can, however, use paths in the request to figure it out (like, say, register your self-hosted WCF process at http://*:8000/path/ instead of http://*:8000/)